# Flutter Model from reqres.in

Tags: flutter

i read code somewhere from github and see 3 models here. this code should be use form get,post,put and delete but before go to far i dont understand why he separate 3 models. maybe someone can explain me what this person thingking. this is the models

[image: project structure]

**user.dart**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'data.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  User({
    required this.data,
  });

  Data data;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

this is **user_info.dart**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user_info.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserInfo {
  String name;
  String job;
  String? id;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  UserInfo({
    required this.name,
    required this.job,
    this.id,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory UserInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserInfoFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserInfoToJson(this);
}
```

this is **data.dart**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Data {
  Data({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.avatar,
  });

  int id;
  String email;
  @JsonKey(name: 'first_name')
  String firstName;
  @JsonKey(name: 'last_name')
  String lastName;
  String avatar;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DataToJson(this);
}
```

this is the github link  https://github.com/sbis04/dio_networking

Answer (score 0):

Using Model to format data, is depend on developer strategy.For example here they want to categorize the user data in to different for. They have User which have a property of data that provide with other model class which is some user informations. They have other model class called UserInfo which hold other user information than Data class.